# PayPal shipping prices for different countries

Tags: paypal

I am setting up an online store using PayPal.
My issue is that I can only choose a fixed price for shipping (og percentage based which isn't relevant)

I am based in Europe, so shipping one item to europe or one item to the US is a huge difference, but I can't find a way to differentiate between them.

I'm aware that this is on the verge of being non-code related, but I'm thinking that there might be a way around this using an api or something along those line?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the shipping on your side, and pass that shipping about over to PayPal as the amount to charge for shipping.  There are several different ways to do this, some of which would depend on how you are currently integrated with PayPal.